# how to combine array of objects by value using reduce( ) in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I am having trouble to use reduce() in TypeScript. I want to reduce objects with a same key/value pair into one array.

I am trying it like so:

```js
    const asdf = sections.reduce<{ [index: number]: any }>((res, section) => {
        return [
          ...res, //error here
          {
            [section.buildingId]: [
              ...(res[section.buildingId] || []),
              section,
            ],
          },
        ]
      },[]) //I think the problem lies here?!
    }
```

sections is an array of objects which all have the key buildingId: number.
I suspect the initialvalue of [] as the source of problems, but I am not quite sure.

the third line gives this error:

> Type '{ [index: number]: any; }' must have a 'Symbol.iterator' method that returns an iterator.ts(2488)

which is strange to me since number is iterable?! or not?

Comment: Please provide a [mre]. See [ask].

Comment: Caused by typo in the generic type, should be an array `sections.reduce<{ [index: number]: any }[]>`

Comment: it moves the errormessage (same as above) to  this line `(res[section?.buildingId ? section.buildingId : 0] || [])` any other clue? i just cannot figure it out..

Comment: If you set the generic argument to `any[]` (https://tsplay.dev/Wok6eW) you can at least run the javascript code - please verify that it is indeed what you intended (the result seems somehow implausible) - if it is, then a more specific template argument can be thought of.

Answer (score 0):

Change the type to Array:

```
const asdf = sections.reduce<Array<any>>((res, section) => {
    return [
      ...res,
      {
        [section.buildingId]: [
          ...(res[section.buildingId] || []),
          section,
        ],
      },
    ]
  },[])
```